# Custom Receiver app local storage

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a Custom Receiver App and wanted to improve flow by adding some "nice-to-have" data in the local storage.

Does chromecast have local storage? Can I use it? Will the storage be  removed when there is no space? Docs?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

The Cast receiver app works like an incognito browser window. Local storage is not supported and no data is persisted between user sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As Leon Nichols stated, there is no local storage.

The workaround I can think of, is to make your custom receiver capable of receiving text messages.
https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-ios/blob/master/receiver/receiver.html

Meanwhile, local storage will be in your sender, and after launching receiver, send a text messages containing your local storage code.